# Why do I need to set KeepAlive to false when using a proxy?.

Tags: c#, http, https, httpwebrequest

I'm using HTTPWebRequest with a proxy. I have noticed if I set KeepAlive to true I get a 407 forbidden exception, when I set keep alive to false it works.

I was just wondering why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because doing a keepalive to a proxy is a pointless waste of bandwidth.  It sounds like your particular proxy server is smart enough to protect itself by issuing a "407" error response.

PS:
The error is actually

> (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Answer (score 1):

If your proxy is HTTP compliant, there is no reason to set KeepAlive to false, unless your proxy requires NTLM authentication.

For NTLM authentication to succeed, you need to have a keep-alive connection. It seems like you are going through such a proxy, that is why it failed with a 407 when keep-alive was enabled.

Comment: Not quite.  If you're using MS NTLM authentication, then certain clients (such as IE 5 or 6, for example), might "send extraneous NTLM requests", generating "407: Proxy Authentication Required" responses.  This issue - along with workarounds - is discussed here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312176

Comment: The support article you cite applies to IE/Wininet only. The question is about HttpWebRequest which does not use Wininet, unless we are talking about a silverlight scenario here.